# Consulta sql de 2 tablas diferentes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo un cuadro que consulta de dos tablas diferentes:

s_USUARIO (idxUsu, nombre, email, celu, domicilio y localidad)

s_PROVINCIAS (idxProv, provincia)

Logro que muestre los datos pero en vez de mostrar el nombre de las provincia muestra la ID de la provincia.

[image: tabla de consulta]

**Este es el código del cuadro:**

```
    <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("sitio", "usuario", "pass", "nombre");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM s_USUARIO";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    ?>

    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="1" align="center" style="line-height:25px;">
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Celular</th>
        <th>Domicilio</th>
        <th>Localidad</th>
        <th>Provincia</th>
        <th>Activo</th>

        </tr>
        <?php
        //Fetch Data form database
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['idxUsu']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['celu']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['domicilio']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['localidad']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['idxProv']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['activo']; ?></td>
                 </tr>
                <?php  } } else {  ?>
          <tr><th colspan="2">No se encontro ninguna data!</th></tr>
            <?php } ?>   
        </table>
```

Si cambio `<td><?php echo $row['idxProv']; ?></td>`  por  `<td><?php echo $row['provincia']; ?></td>` salta error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque estas mostrando el **ID provincia**, modifica tu consulta haciendo un inner join con la tabla provincias para obtener el nombre:

```
$sql = "SELECT U.*, P.provincia AS 'NombreProvincia' FROM s_USUARIO AS U INNER JOIN s_PROVINCIAS AS P ON U.idxProv = P.idxProv";
```

Luego en tu codigo modifica la ante-ultima columna que en vez de seleccionar 'idxProv' traiga 'NombreProvincia':

```
<td><?php echo $row['NombreProvincia']; ?></td>
```

Saludos!

Comment: La comparación en el inner join tendría que ser `U.idxProv = P.idxProv` en vez de `U.idxUsu = P.idxProv`

Comment: Si es verdad, ahí corregí el query gracias por avisar.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! Y si hago otra columna llamando otra tabla. Cómo puedo hacer? Intente de copiar lo tuyo y cambiar el nombre de las acciones pero no funciono

Comment: Cómo se llama tu tabla y tu campo en común?

Comment: Tabla: s_evento Campo: nombre